# WebSocket connection to '' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 405

Tags: apex, visualforce, batch, platform-event

I am trying to subscribe to platform events on VF page. But getting WebSocket connection error. Not sure what am I doing wrong.

[image]

```
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.cometd, '/newCometd/cometd.js')}"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.scripts, '/scripts/jquery.min.js')}"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.cometd, '/newCometd/json2.js')}"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.cometd, '/newCometd/jquery.cometd.js')}"/>


    (function($){
      $(document).ready(function() {
          // Connect to the CometD endpoint
          $.cometd.init({
             url: window.location.protocol+'//'+window.location.hostname+'/cometd/44.0/',
             requestHeaders: { Authorization: 'OAuth {!$Api.Session_ID}'}
         });

         // Subscribe to a topic. JSON-encoded update will be returned
         // in the callback
         $.cometd.subscribe('/event/Upload_Notification__e', function(message) {
             //callRefresh();
          });
      });
   })(jQuery)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. This was recently resolved [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9062I000000Qy9gQAC).

The resolution (copied from that link) involves splitting the init() call into separate configure() and handshake() calls so that websocketEnabled can be disabled.

Note: I was also getting an appendMessageTypeToURL error which the following code fixes by adding an additional requestHeader.

```
$.cometd.configure({
     url: window.location.protocol+'//'+window.location.hostname+'/cometd/49.0',
     requestHeaders: { Authorization: 'OAuth {!$Api.Session_ID}'},
                     appendMessageTypeToURL : false
     });
 
console.log('before handshake');

// disable websockets
$.cometd.websocketEnabled = false; 
      
$.cometd.handshake();

console.log('before addListener');  
    
$.cometd.addListener('/meta/handshake', 
                     function(message) {
                         $.cometd.subscribe('/event/Event_On_Leads__e', 
                                            function(message) {                    
                                                console.log('testing subscribed');
                                            }
                         );   
                     });
```